# fixing byte outofMemory Android

Tags: java, android, exception, memory

I am trying to fix outofMemory in my application that has a function as follows:

```
   public byte[] processByteArray (int bits) throws OutofMemoryError {
   byte [] arr =new byte [bits];
   //do something and 
   return arr;
 }
```

I am not sure about what user provides for value bits and hence get exception Dalvik saying  536870812 byte allocation exceeds the 67108864 byte maximum heap size.

So, I did something like this which is not good, but for now fixes issue:

declare arr privately in the class and access that inside function like this :

```
       public byte[] processByteArray (int bits) throws OutofMemoryError {
   if(bits<=67108864) {
      byte [] arr =new byte [bits]; //tell me if this is right..!
      }
   //do something and 
   return arr;
 }
```

I am not sure how else I can fix this issue, I want to know the max limit byte [] arr can take in my function , I mean I want to know parameter- "bits" limit in new byte [bits]; 
. Please educate me.. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`getMemoryClass()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29) to get the find the limit, instead of assigning a magic number.

Comment: Thanks , but I need to know the max limit byte[] arr can take in my function.

Comment: Exactly, use the `getMemoryClass()` to determine the heap size, and then use that as your limit. The heap is going to be different on every phone.

Comment: wonderful, but this is a class and I am not expending it from anything. how will I access ActivityManager inside this.

Comment: How is this `just a class` it has to be connected to your project somehow. Find the link and get that value to it. If you don't care just use do it the way it is now, but don't be surprised when you run into problems in the future.

Comment: Thank you I am gonna use your suggestion..!